# Having trouble passings params to embedded action in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

Working on some legacy code (Rails v2.3) and I've become stuck.

I have a view that uses the embed tag to run an action that produces a PDF.
Copying code from the other working view in my project, I have the embed code link to the controller action:

`<embed height="400px" width="95%" name="plugin" src="<%= formatted_report_reports_path(:pdf) %>" type="application/pdf" />`

The src links to an action called `report` that needs the values for some params on the view called `params[:startdate]` and `params[:enddate]`, but those become `nil` in the `def report` action once the embed code runs.

I proved to myself that the `embed` tag works by hardcoding some date values into the `def report` action, so at least I know that works when it does actually have dates.

I thought I could pass the `params[:]` to the src like this:

`src="<%= formatted_report_reports_path(params[:startdate], :pdf) %>"`

but that returns an error like this:

`undefined method 'has_key?' for :pdf:Symbol`

In my research I found that the `:pdf` symbol is what is used for determing the "format" like what's in my default connections routes. I tried adding another connection for using the `:startdate` symbol along with the format symbol, but that also didn't work:

`map.connect ':controller/:action/:startdate.:format'`

It had been my understanding that `params[:]` keep their values throughout the program, and I've hit a wall understanding why they're nil once the embed code runs the action. Some other threads I came across mention that once another `:action` is called in a `:controller` the params values are wiped until they're set again, and I guess that's what's happening, but how do I set them again so that the embed code will have it?

Code I'm looking at:

report.html.erb

```
<%- form_tag report_reports_url, :method => 'get' do -%>
<p>
    <%= label_tag :startdate, 'Start Date Range' %>
    <%= calendar_date_select_tag :startdate, params[:startdate] %>
    to
    <%= calendar_date_select_tag :enddate, params[:enddate] %>
</p>
            <%= submit_tag 'Run Report' %>
        <%- end -%>
    </p>
  </div>
  
 <p></p>
 
 <%- if params[:startdate].nil? -%>
 <%- else -%>
<div id = 'results'>
<embed height="400px" width="95%" name="plugin" src="<%= formatted_report_reports_path(:pdf) %>" type="application/pdf" />
</div>
<%- end -%>
```

reports_controller.rb

```
def report        
      respond_to do |format|
                    format.html do
                    end
                    format.pdf do
                    pdf = make_report_pdf(params[:startdate],params[:enddate])                  
                     if pdf.nil?                          
                     else
                       send_file pdf, :type=> "application/pdf", :disposition => "inline"
                     end
                    end
                   end
    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...the params values are wiped until they're set again, and I guess that's what's happening, but how do I set them again so that the embed code will have it?

Yes, this is the case. The `params` only have the lifespan of a given request.

I'm guessing a little here, but I think you need this for your path call:

```rb
formatted_report_reports_path(:startdate => params[:startdate], :format => :pdf)
```

Comment: Thank you! That was it! Formatting it that way passed those params over to the action and worked exactly how I needed. Thanks for saving my weekend